# How to connect two zod scheme's?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, zod

There are two schemes

they are in different files

You can somehow combine it according to the condition that if the isSurname field is selected, make the prevName/prevSurname fields mandatory and vice versa, or combine it according to the condition (I was looking in the direction of refine)

```
  const A = z.object({
    name: z.string(),
    surname: z.string(),
  });

  const B = z.object({
    isSurname: z.boolean(),
    prevName: z.string(),
    prevSurname: z.string(),
  });

  A.merge(B)
```

Comment: Need more clarity. Do you want B.prevName and B,prevSurname to be mandatory if B.isSurname is true? And they will become optional if B.isSurname is false?